# How to eliminate spacing between divs using display:inline-block?

Tags: css

Im trying to do some horizontal layout of divs but get an unwanted "margin" after the divs.
http://jsfiddle.net/Yzxpu/

When I change the the markup and delete the spaces or line breaks the problem gets fixed for the horizontal spacing, but still there is vertical spacing under the divs. And the markup looks bad. 
http://jsfiddle.net/Yzxpu/1/

I don't want to see any red (except for the far right, it will get fixed as the right-margin % gets set)

I'm using latest Chrome as web browser.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY THIS

http://jsfiddle.net/Yzxpu/10/

CHANGE YOUR CSS

```
#t-newsAndInfo{background-color:red; overflow:hidden}

#t-newsAndInfo div {float:left;}
```

REMOVE `"DISPLAY"` FROM `#t-newsAndInfo div`

Comment: Stackoverflow wants you to post the code that solves the problem.  Just putting a link up to jsfiddle is not best practice here.  If jsfiddle ever goes down then your link will be useless.

Comment: ohk thats gr8 so you shouldnt use jsfiddle from now onwrds

Comment: @lokase: we are here to solve the op problem, it does not matter whether you use fiddle or put your code in stackoverflow, its just a method to explain your answer

Comment: I never said to stop linking to jsfiddle.  Posters should link to jsfiddle if they want BUT they also need to post the relevant solution code. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Comment: I answered this as correct after all because as you say the inline-block display becomes useless as I see it.

Answer (score 3):

By adding: margin:0; and padding:0; to the CSS it fixes the vertical issue, because browers add their own default settings you would be advised to use a reset.css sheet to set everything back to 0.

The fiddle with the fix:  http://jsfiddle.net/ynemx/
Reset CSS: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Thank you! This looks the most promising to me, so Ill try and implement this fix.

Comment: As it only fixes on of the two problems I had to go with the float solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to float:left the inner divs:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yzxpu/15/

```
#t-newsAndInfo{background-color:red; overflow:hidden;}

#t-newsAndInfo div {
    background-color:lightyellow;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 31.11111111111111%;/*((900-(30+30))/3)/900*/
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    /*margin-right: 3.111111111%;*/
    /*margin-right: 2.99999999999%;*/
}
```

Comment: why you have display:inline-block if you are using float:left ?? any resns ??

Comment: Thank you to, it worked OK, but I'm trying not to use float for this, and hope to find a better solution.

Comment: Is there no other way to get the divs wrapped and "omit" spaces and such except using float?

Comment: I implemented this after all and it works for now, hope it also works when I'm going responsive with the page.